# New video listings appearing slow/delayed than previously. Any way to make them appear instantly as they did previously?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've been using the following query for a long time now and it's been quickly showing me the most recent videos as soon as they are live, until recently.

```
/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet&maxResults=3&fields=items(id%2Ckind%2Csnippet(description%2CpublishedAt%2Cthumbnails%2Fmedium%2Ctitle%2Ctype))&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&key={API_KEY}
```

But for the last few weeks / month or so, it appears delayed by several minutes, and when I tested it against web scraping the channel page, it only occasionally beat it.

For my specific purposes, swiftness is essential. So I'm curious if there is another method that will get me the same information more quickly (Note: I am not the channel owner and I need to check several channels at a time).

Comment: how are we suppose to answer this?

Comment: By letting me know if anyone knows of alternative ways to get the information more quickly or any other tricks that might exist. Or confirm that no alternative methods exist.